# Magento 2 Bottle Deposit Extension

Tags: magento2, price, extensions

I'm looking for a good bottle deposit (in german "Pfand") extension for a Magento 2 Store.

I found an extension for Magento 1 here:
https://mage-people.com/product/bottle-deposit-deposit-fees-pfand-extension-for-magento/

The german right has extra fees on bottles called bottle deposit (Pfand in german) which you have to pay when buying a bottle.

The extension has to provide the functionality that I can add a extra bottle deposit to each product.
this extra fee needs to be displayed in the cart and checkout and ultimately the customer needs to be charged the extra fee.

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: @SukumarGorai is this explanation good enough?

Comment: I still have big needs for an extension which solves this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with Magento Fixed Product Taxes.